# Fiction featuring illegal elements

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, publishing, age

I am working on a work of (historical) fiction, where an important element for plot and audience experience is a sexual encounter with an underaged person. I plan to publish this work worldwide, but mostly in the UK and US markets.

I know certain depictions of underage sexual relations have gotten people in trouble, yet others seem to have passed without much incident; in particular in literature.

Legally, what is the safe barrier of approach, particularly in these regions? Does it differ in Literature, Film, or Video Games? I am considering adaptation, too.

Though the work is not specifically erotica, to some it could easily be read as such.

Comment: "I know certain depictions of underage sexual relations have gotten people in trouble" can you give an example? Public backlash is not a legal issue.

Comment: Example (cited in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_pornography): https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2005-03-04/canadian-arrested-for-importing-loli-porn-manga (manga, so presumably not based on real children, which makes it similar to this question)

Comment: @BrianDrake Yeah, that was the main example to come to mind for me in matters of "no actual people harmed". Such depictions appear illegal in many jurisdictions.